# How do I update formula range in a macro?

Tags: excel, vba, reference, cell

I have a formula in A1 that is fed with data from a different workbook. It's only a reference to this other workbook, there aren't any calculations.
This second workbook is updated on a monthly basis so the cell I'm interested in referring to is offset one cell to the right each month.
How can I write a macro that tells my current formula in A1 to use the same formula but moving it one place to the right? It'd be something like: `[Book1]Sheet1!C15` to `[Book1]Sheet1!D15`. Thanks!

Comment: That might depend how complicate your formula is, I would probably do a search and replace... an example of your actual formula would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Range.Precedents` to get the cells a particular `Range` depends on.

```
'get the cell:
Dim theCell As Range
Set theCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

'get its first "precedent" Range:
Dim precedent As Range
Set precedent = theCell.Precedents(1)

'rewrite the formula, offsetting the precedent by 1 column:
theCell.Formula = "=" & precedent.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Address(External:=True)
```

Obviously this makes a lot of assumptions and will need to be adjusted to your specific needs, but you don't need to parse any formulas to offset its *precedent* cells when you're looking at a formula that's simply `=SomeCellAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

First put this small UDF in a standard module:

```
Public Function NextCellOver(s As String) As String
    arr = Split(s, "!")
    addy = Range(arr(1)).Offset(0, 1).Address
    NextCellOver = arr(0) & "!" & addy
End Function
```

It will accept a string that ends with something like `!Z99` and return a string ending with `!AA99`.  *(Basically one column to the right.)*

Then enter:

```
Sub marine()
    With Range("A1")
        .Formula = NextCellOver(.Formula)
    End With
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
End Sub
```

To apply this to the cell in question.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.